# Possible to continue using AutoNumber Type? (with Access frontend & SQL Server backend)

Tags: autonumber

I feel like this has to be somewhat of a common question, however I cannot seem to find the answer via search, so here goes:

We just moved all of our tables to a SQL Server backend and are looking to continue using MS Access as a frontend because of the friendly UI. We do, however, have a couple of tables that use the AutoNumber type which I have learned SQL Server simply converted to the "bigint" data type.

Now, I've already figured out how to make views that utilize the "CAST" function to convert away from "bigint" when I am linking my tables from the backend (this is so that MS ACCESS can read the tables rather than giving me #deleted values), however this leaves my tables of course with no AutoNumber option still. **Is there a solution to this? I'd really like to continue using an auto incremental column to be used as a PK for our purposes with these tables.**

Thanks for any/all help. It's greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Setting Identity to true with an int type is the same as autonumber.